# Null Pointer exception in the getView method of BaseAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I getting the null pointer exception in getView() of my CustomAdapter here is the complete code.

```
private class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    LayoutInflater viewInflator;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context)
    {
        viewInflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() 
    {
        return weekDate.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) 
    {
        return arg0;
    }

    public long getItemId(int arg0) 
    {
        return arg0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View createView, ViewGroup viewGroup) 
    {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(viewInflator != null)
            holder = (ViewHolder) createView.getTag();
        else
        {
            createView = viewInflator.inflate(R.layout.vehicle_detail_listview, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.setTextView( (TextView) createView.findViewById(R.id.listContent) );
            createView.setTag(holder);
        }

        holder.getTextView().setText(weekDate.get(position));

        return createView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder
    {
        private TextView textView;

        public TextView getTextView() 
        {
            return textView;
        }

        public void setTextView(TextView textView) 
        {
            this.textView = textView;
        }
    }
}
```

now the null pointer exception arise at line `holder = (ViewHolder) createView.getTag();`

there is two layout main & vehicle_detail_listview.

- Main layout : contain the one textView & listView
- vehicle_detail_listview :  one text view

Now from the onCreate() of the Activity I am writing this :

```
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Please let me know where i am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This shoud be like this :

```
        if(createView != null)
            holder = (ViewHolder) createView.getTag();
        else
        {
            createView = viewInflator.inflate(R.layout.vehicle_detail_listview, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.setTextView( (TextView) createView.findViewById(R.id.listContent) );
            createView.setTag(holder);
        }
```

You don't need to check if viewInflator != null but you use createView just after without verifying it...
You can look [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html) for an example, but apart of that error, your code seems code.

EDIT : Except the view holder, look the way it is in the example I linked, the class must be static to avoid memory leak, and don't bother using getter and setter.

Comment: yeah you are right, now after checking link the exception(Null Pointer Exception) is coming at creatView = viewInflator.inflate(parameter..) method..

Comment: @Amit you need to pass parent to the method inflate :
createView = viewInflator.inflate(R.layout.vehicle_detail_listview, parent, false);
                        
Look at the example.

Comment: Right.. I get it working..
In my code i forget to put viewInflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);

public CustomAdapter(Context context)
    {
        viewInflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }



CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this);
through this constructor its initialized.. 

Now working fine..

thanks

Comment: Ok ! At the first time, I also thought you hadn't initialized viewInflator, but in the code you posted, it was there. It seem I wasn't wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

it is bcoz you have not set the tag and you are calling getTag...

replace

```
if(viewInflator != null) with 
if(createView != null)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply & suggestion. I have replaced but now exception is coming at createView = viewInflator.inflate(R.layout.vehicle_detail_listview, null);

Comment: try this:  viewInflator = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);